# CosmosDB SQL String functions not working with a join?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection in DocumentDB with objects that look like this:

```
{
"id":"1de03a93-729d-43da-985a-12584079b4f8",
"Components":[
     {
     "Name":"MyComponentName1",
     "Value": 12345
     },
     {
     "Name":"MyComponentName2",
     "Value": 34567
     },
     {
     "Name":"MyComponentName3",
     "Value": 56789
     }
     ]
     ...other properties irrelevant to question...
}
```

When querying CosmosDB, I have the following query:

```
SELECT VALUE d FROM c
JOIN d IN c.Components
WHERE d.Name="MyComponentName1"
```

which correctly returns:

```
{
"Name":"MyComponentName1",
"Value":12345
}
```

However, when I attempt to query based on a String operator:

```
SELECT VALUE d FROM c
JOIN d IN c.Components
WHERE CONTAINS(d.Name,'MyComponent') --OR STARTSWITH OR ENDSWITH
```

I get no results.

If I take the *same query as above* but I add an `id` restriction to the where clause:

```
SELECT VALUE d FROM c
JOIN d IN c.Components
WHERE CONTAINS(d.Name,'MyComponent')
AND c.id = "1de03a93-729d-43da-985a-12584079b4f8"
```

I get back the results I expect, but obviously only for that `id`. I need all of the documents that match the String operator.

Is this a bug with CosmosDB, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick,

Make sure that you're following all the continuations when you execute this query. Please keep in mind that the query w/ Contains will result in a full scan and hence it might not finish in a single continuation. This is the same case w/ EndsWith. For StartsWith, however, it should utilize the index, but only if the collection index policy define range index on strings; otherwise, it will still be a scan.

Comment: Ah, that was it. I knew this would be a poor performing query, I was just trying to pull some test data while investigating another situation.

I was running this query in the *Data Explorer* and getting no results.

Running the query in the *Query Explorer* correctly handles the continuation and displays the appropriate results.